# jQuery hide/access element in top/main window from iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, window, parent

I am using a CRM system where I can't control the HTML the system generates. This is the simplest form of the HTML markup I am dealing with.

```
<button id="cmdedit">Edit</button>
<textarea cols="30" rows="10"> Hi there </textarea>
<iframe src="s_blank.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I want to hide cmdedit `<button>` after page load. I can only change the contents of that `<textarea>` which is then inserted into the DOM as HTML content of the following `<iframe>` on page load. I can include `<script>` tag and write javascript or Jquery statements that gets into that `<iframe>` and the javascript alert statements work just fine. I tried to hide the `<button>` using the following code but neither works after page load.

**Script inside iframe:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){         
        var MyRoleList = "@me.rolelist@";
        if (MyRoleList.indexOf(",9875,") > -1){         
            alert('aaa');   
            $('#cmdedit').hide();     
        }
     });
  </script>
```

**System generated full HTML**:

```html
<html lang="en"><head>
    <title>Examinee Notice</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/images/favicon.ico">
 <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="/images/favicon.ico">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/ccss/styles_common_basic_404048.css?version=201711.05">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/jquery/jquery-confirm-master/css/jquery-confirm.css?v=201711.05">
    <script language="JavaScript" src="/jquery/jquery.js?v=201711.05"></script><style></style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/jquery-confirm-master/dist/jquery-confirm.min.js?v=201711.05"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="/Ajax/uta/uta.js?v=201711.05"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="/js/ssvalidate.js?v=201711.05"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ssfieldfunctions.js?v=201711.05"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ssfunctions.js?v=201711.05"></script>
    <script language="javascript">
        var _iseditmode=false;
            function jqueryalert(msg, confirmfn) {
                $.confirm({
                    title: "Hey Muhammad",
                    content: msg,
                    icon: 'fa fa-exclamation-triangle',
                    theme: 'material',
                    animation: 'scale',
                    closeAnimation: 'scale',
                    type: 'orange',
                    buttons: {
                        confirm: {
                            text: "OK",
                            btnClass: 'btn-orange',
                            keys: ['enter'],
                            action: function() {
                                if (confirmfn) {
                                    confirmfn();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            function jqueryconfirm(msg, confirmfn, cancelfn) {
                $.confirm({
                    title: "Hey Muhammad",
                    content: msg,
                    icon: 'fa fa-exclamation-triangle',
                    theme: 'material',
                    animation: 'scale',
                    closeAnimation: 'scale',
                    type: 'orange',
                    buttons: {
                        confirm: {
                            text: "Yes",
                            btnClass: 'btn-orange',
                            action: function() {
                                if (confirmfn) {
                                    confirmfn();
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        cancel: {
                            text: "No",
                            action: function() {
                                if (cancelfn) {
                                    cancelfn();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            function jqueryprompt(msg, confirmfn, cancelfn) {
                $.confirm({
                    title: "Hey Muhammad",
                    content: msg,
                    icon: 'fa fa-exclamation-triangle',
                    theme: 'material',
                    animation: 'scale',
                    closeAnimation: 'scale',
                    type: 'orange',
                    buttons: {
                        confirm: {
                            text: "Continue",
                            btnClass: 'btn-orange',
                            keys: ['enter'],
                            action: function() {
                                if (confirmfn) {
                                    if (!confirmfn(this.$content)) {
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        cancel: {
                            text: "Cancel",
                            keys: ['esc'],
                            action: function() {
                                if (cancelfn) {
                                    cancelfn();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        function no_error()
        { return true; }
        //window.onerror=no_error;

        function getsrc()
        { var frm=window.frames["page_win"].document.forms[0];
            if(frm==null) return "";
            var valuestr='\n var frm_inp=document.forms[0];\n';
            var ctltype;
            for (var i=0;i<frm.elements.length;i++)
            { ctltype=frm.elements[i].type.toLowerCase();
                if(ctltype=='radio'||ctltype=='checkbox')
                { if (frm.elements[i].checked)
                        valuestr+='\nfrm_inp.elements['+i+'].checked=true;';
                }
                else
                    valuestr+='\nfrm_inp.elements['+i+'].value=decodeURIComponent("'+encodeURIComponent(frm.elements[i].value)+'");';
            }

            return valuestr;
        }



        function puttxt()
        {
            window.frames["page_win"].document.writeln(document.frmtext.txt.value);
            window.frames["page_win"].document.close();
            var cmd=document.getElementById('cmdprint');
            if(cmd!=null)
                cmd.style.display="inline";
            cmd=document.getElementById('cmdemail');
            if(cmd!=null)
                cmd.style.display="inline";
            cmd=document.getElementById('cmdpdf');
            if(cmd!=null)
                cmd.style.display="inline";
            
            cmd=document.getElementById('cmddocx');
            if(cmd!=null)
                cmd.style.display="inline";
            
            cmd=document.getElementById('cmdemailpdf');
            if(cmd!=null)
                cmd.style.display="inline";
            cmd=document.getElementById('cmdemaildoc');
            if(cmd!=null)
                cmd.style.display="inline";
            if (window.frames["page_win"]!=null && window.frames["page_win"].ss_load)
                window.frames["page_win"].ss_load();
            if(window.frames["page_win"]!=null)window.frames["page_win"].focus();
        }

        function editdoc(button)
        {
            if(!_iseditmode)
            {window.frames["page_win"].location.href='/s_editor.html';
                button.value="Preview";



                _iseditmode=true;
            }else
            {  document.frmtext.txt.value=window.frames["page_win"].oCKeditor.getData();

                window.frames["page_win"].document.writeln(document.frmtext.txt.value);
                window.frames["page_win"].document.close();
                button.value="Edit";
                _iseditmode=false;
            }

            switchbut(button.form,'cmdprint');
            switchbut(button.form,'cmdnewin');
            switchbut(button.form,'cmdemail');
            switchbut(button.form,'cmdemailpdf');
            switchbut(button.form,'cmdemaildoc');
            switchbut(button.form,'cmdpdf');
            switchbut(button.form,'cmdsavehtml');
            switchbut(button.form,'cmdsavepdf');
            switchbut(button.form,'cmdsavedoc');
            if ($('#functable').css("display") == "none")
                $('#functable').css("display", "table");
            else
                $('#functable').css("display", "none");
        }

        function switchbut(frm ,ctl)
        { var octl =frm.elements[ctl];
            if (octl!=null)
            {
                octl.disabled=!octl.disabled;
                if (octl.disabled)
                    $('[name="'+ctl+'"]').css("display", "none");
                else
                    $('[name="'+ctl+'"]').css("display", "inline");
            }
        }
        function CheckIsIE()
        {
            return (navigator.appName.toUpperCase().indexOf('MICROSOFT')>-1) ;

        }


        function printdoc()
        {

            if (CheckIsIE() == true)
            {
                document.page_win.focus();
                document.page_win.print();
            }
            else
            {
                window.frames['page_win'].focus();
                window.frames['page_win'].print();
            }

        }

        function savelocal(fname)
        {
            window.frames["page_win"].document.execCommand('SaveAs',null,fname)
        }


        function saveserver(type)
        { 
            if(_iseditmode) {
                document.frmtext.txt.value=window.frames["page_win"].oCKeditor.getData();
            }
            var frm=document.frmtext;
            frm.filename.value=frm.filename.value.replace(/\.html/,"");
            frm.filename.value=frm.filename.value.replace(/\.pdf/,"");

            if(frm.mfolderid.value=='') {
                alert("Please select a folder name to save to.");
                return false;
            }
            
            var html = "<div class=\"form-group\" style=\"text-align:center\"><div style=\"margin:5px\">Please enter a file name.</div><input class=\"Large\" type=\"text\" placeholder=\"File Name\" class=\"form-control\" id=\"filenameprompt\" value=\"" + frm.filename.value + "\"/></div>";
            jqueryprompt(html, function(promptobj) {
                var frm = document.frmtext;
                var newf = promptobj.find("#filenameprompt").val();
                if (newf == '') {
                    alert("File name cannot be empty.");
                    return false;
                } else if (!isValidFileName(newf)) {
                    alert("File name contains invalid characters (;,#,=,?)");
                    return false;
                }
                frm.filename.value=newf.replace(/\s|\/|\\/g,'_');
                saveserversb(type)
                return true;
            });
            
        }
        function saveserversb(type) {
            
            saveserversb2(type);
            
        }
        function saveserversb2(type) {
            var frm=document.frmtext;
            var id=frm.mfolderid.value;
            if (id.indexOf('-')>0) {
                frm.objectid.value=id.substring(0,id.indexOf('-'));
                frm.folderid.value=id.substring(id.indexOf('-')+1);
            } else {
                frm.folderid.value=frm.mfolderid.value;
            }
            frm.action='s_savetextfile.jsp?type='+type;
            frm.target='page_win';
            frm.submit();
        }
    function newwind(frm)
    { var src;
        if(_iseditmode)
            src=window.frames["page_win"].oCKeditor.getData();
        else
            src=frm.txt.value;

        OpenWindow=window.open("", "newwin", "menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,width=550,height=300,status=no,resizable=yes,dependent=yes,alwaysRaised=yes");
        OpenWindow.document.write(src);
        OpenWindow.document.close()
    }

    function newwinda()
    {
        var frm = document.frmtext;
        var inf = frm.txt.value;
        win = window.open("", "newwina", "menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,width=650,height=500,status=no,resizable=yes,dependent=yes,alwaysRaised=no");
        win.document.write("" + inf + "");
        win.document.close();
    }

    function gotohcai()
    {   alert('When submitting to HCAI, please be aware that the submission time frame can vary between 0-120 min. If your submission is surpassing this time frame, please notify SmartSimple Support.', function() {
            location.href="/Apps/Bridge/hc_submissions.jsp?fieldid=1274403&entity=24&objectid=1127956&appid=102946";
        });
    }
    function gotosignority() {
        showsave("Load in Progress");
        location.href="/Apps/Bridge/sg_signority.jsp?fieldid=1274403&entity=24&objectid=1127956&appid=102946&codedid=QHJrJ0keIhgKFlALJGc1KgRXEAcuXRsTH2JcU0VNZl8~&islb=0&exportpdf=0&ismwin=0";
    }



        function emailpdf() {
            if(_iseditmode)
                document.frmtext.txt.value=window.frames["page_win"].oCKeditor.getData();

            var frm=document.frmtext;
            frm.body.value=frm.txt.value;

            
            emailpdfsb();
            
        }
        function emailpdfsb() {
            var frm=document.frmtext;
            window.open("", "comp_win", "menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,width=550,height=300,status=no,resizable=yes,dependent=yes,alwaysRaised=yes");
            frm.action="/Comm/ms_makepdf.jsp";
            frm.target='comp_win';
            frm.submit();
        }

    function pdfwrite(frm)
    {if(_iseditmode)
            document.frmtext.txt.value=window.frames["page_win"].oCKeditor.getData();

        var frm=document.frmtext;
        new_win = window.open('','new_win', 'menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,width=600,height=340,status=no,resizable=yes,top=200,left=200,dependent=yes,alwaysRaised=yes');
        new_win.opener = window;
        new_win.focus();

        frm.body.value=frm.txt.value;
        frm.action="/pdfWriter";
        frm.target='new_win';
        frm.submit();
    }
    function docxwrite(frm)
    {if(_iseditmode)
            document.frmtext.txt.value=window.frames["page_win"].oCKeditor.getData();

        var frm=document.frmtext;
        new_win = window.open('','new_win', 'menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,width=600,height=340,status=no,resizable=yes,top=200,left=200,dependent=yes,alwaysRaised=yes');
        new_win.opener = window;
        new_win.focus();

        frm.body.value=frm.txt.value;
        frm.action="/docxWriter";
        
        frm.submit();
    }

    function showconv()
    {
        document.getElementById("saveinprogress").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("sip").src="/images/saveinprogress.gif";
    }

    function switchlang(lang) {
        var url=location.href;
        if (url.indexOf("cmdlang")>-1)
            url=url.substring(0,url.indexOf("cmdlang"));
        url+="&cmdlang="+lang;
        location.href=url;
    }


    function gohtml(){
        if(_iseditmode)
            document.frmtext.txt.value=window.frames["page_win"].oCKeditor.getData();
        var frm=document.frmtext;
        var jsrc=getsrc();
        if(jsrc.length>0)
            frm.txt.value+="\<script language=javascript\>"+jsrc+"\</script\>";
        frm.body.value=frm.txt.value;
        frm.iswebpage.value="1";
        popupNote();
        frm.action="/s_viewpagehtml.jsp";
        frm.target='comp_win';
        window.open("", "comp_win", "menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,width=736,height=700,status=no,resizable=yes,dependent=yes,alwaysRaised=yes");
        frm.submit();
        self.close();
    }

    function popupNote(){
        alert("Right click the new popup page and \"Save as\" a HTML file.");
    }

    function setfrmheight() {
  
        $("#page_win").height($("body").height() - ($("#header").height()));
    }

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ssfunctions.js?v=201711.05"></script>

    <style>
        html,body{
            height:100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        body{
            min-width:100%;
            max-width:100%;
            width:100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body scroll="no" onload="puttxt();setfrmheight();" onresize="setfrmheight();">

    <!--<div style="display:none;width:100%;height:100%;top:0;left:0;position:absolute;background:#FFFFFF;z-Index:200;opacity:0.8;filter:alpha(opacity=80);text-align:center" id="saveinprogress"><table height="100%" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td valign="middle" align="center"><img src='/images/blank.gif' id="sip"><br><strong style='font-size:16pt;color:#697F39'>PDF Creation in Progress</strong><br><strong style='font-size:12pt;color:#697F39'>Please Wait</strong></td></tr></table></div>-->
    <div style="display:none;width:100%;height:100%;top:0;left:0;position:absolute;background:#FFFFFF;z-Index:200;opacity:0.8;filter:alpha(opacity=80);text-align:center" id="saveinprogress"><table width="100%" height="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody><tr><td valign="middle" align="center"><img src="/images/blank.gif" id="sip" alt="Save In Progress"><br><div style="font-size:16pt;font-weight:bold;color:#697F39" id="smsg">PDF Creation in Progress</div><br><strong style="font-size:12pt;color:#697F39">Please Wait</strong></td></tr></tbody></table></div>


    <div id="header">
        
        
        <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
            <tbody><tr>
                <th class="Title">Web Page View Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>
        
        <form name="frmtext" target="page_win" action="s_savetextfile.jsp" method="POST">
        <input name="ss_formtoken" id="ss_formtoken" value="0A0133DEE42C7A11D0AA8C8988695CEDAA905422B38099B3C0C9B463CEDC7663" type="hidden">
        <input value="1127956" name="objectid" type="hidden">
        <input value="" name="folderid" type="hidden">
        <input value="0" name="peopleid" type="hidden">
        <input value="0" name="varcontactid" type="hidden">
        <input value="2" name="format" type="hidden">
        <input value="" name="pswd" type="hidden">
        <input value="1" name="peopletypeid" type="hidden">
        <input value="1" name="iswebpage" type="hidden">
        <input value="" name="body" type="hidden">
        <input value="" name="subject" type="hidden">
        <input value="" name="cc" type="hidden">
        <input value="0" name="touser" type="hidden">
        <input value="0" name="maxp" type="hidden">
        <input value="Examinee_Notice_1127956" name="pdfname" type="hidden">
        <input value="Examinee_Notice_1127956" name="filename" type="hidden">
        <input value="24" name="entity" type="hidden">
        <input value="102946" name="appid" type="hidden">
        
        <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td class="Title">

                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td colspan="3">

                                
                                <input name="cmdedit" id="cmdedit" class="ButtonSm" value="Edit" onclick="editdoc(this)" type="button">
                                
                                <input name="cmdemailpdf" id="cmdemailpdf" style="display: inline;" class="ButtonSm" value="Email as PDF" onclick="emailpdf()" type="button">
                                
                                <input name="cmdpdf" id="cmdpdf" style="display: inline;" class="ButtonSm" value="Export as PDF" onclick="pdfwrite();" type="button">
                                

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>
        
        
        <table id="functable" name="functable" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td class="Title">

                    <div style="float:right;padding:4px 4px 0 0">
                        
                        Folder Name: <select name="mfolderid" class="AppNav" style="max-width:300px"><option value=""> --Select a folder-- </option><option value="1267619">Active Drafts</option>
<option value="1267614">Active Medical File</option>
<option value="1269758">Adjuster Service Requests (ARF - Portal)</option>
<option value="1267610" selected="">Adjuster, Assessor, Examinee And Legal Rep Communications</option>
<option value="1267616">Archived Medical File</option>
<option value="1274156">Client Invoices</option>
<option value="1269519">Correspondence - Notice to Assessor forms &amp; Assessment Plans</option>
<option value="1267612">Correspondence - Other</option>
<option value="1267620">Final Reports</option>
<option value="1267615">IME Guidelines Kits</option>
<option value="1267621">Informed Consent</option>
<option value="1267623">Provider Invoices</option>
<option value="1269372">Invoices and Consents</option>
<option value="1269448">Medical Briefs and Insurer Examination Reports</option>
<option value="1273039">Previous Drafts</option>
<option value="1267609">Production and Court Prep</option>
<option value="1273836">Referral Mandate</option>
</select>

                        
                    </div>


                    
                    <input name="cmdsavepdf" class="Button" value="Save To Server as PDF" onclick="saveserver(1)" type="button">
                    



                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>
        

        <textarea cols="0" rows="0" name="txt" style="display:none">
&lt;!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"&gt;
&lt;html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"&gt;
   &lt;head&gt;
      &lt;meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /&gt;
      &lt;title&gt;Claimant Notice&lt;/title&gt;
      &lt;style type="text/css"&gt;  
         Table td 
         {
         padding: 3px;  
         vertical-align: top;
         }
         body
         {
         font-size:10pt;font-family:arial;    
         }
      &lt;/style&gt;
      &lt;script language="JavaScript" src="/jquery/jquery.js?v=201711.05"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
      &lt;style&gt;&lt;/style&gt;
      &lt;script type="text/javascript"&gt;
         $(document).ready(function(){                      
         alert('aaa');   
        $('#cmdedit').hide();   
          }
         });
      &lt;/script&gt;
   &lt;/head&gt;

   &lt;body&gt;
      &lt;table width="700px" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"&gt;
         &lt;tbody&gt;
            &lt;tr&gt;
               &lt;td&gt;                    
                  Test Test      
               &lt;/td&gt;
            &lt;/tr&gt;
         &lt;/tbody&gt;
      &lt;/table&gt;
   &lt;/body&gt;
&lt;/html&gt;</textarea>

    </form>
    </div>
      <div class="iframe_ipad">
    <iframe src="/s_blank.html" id="page_win" name="page_win" style="height: 71px;" width="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
      </div>




</body></html>
```

Comment: You can wrap your hide function within setTimeout function, but if time for appear the DOM element is different on every load, it is not an option. However, there is plugin for jQuery which is called 'jquery.initialize'. So, you can set in document ready this; $('#cmdedit').initialize(function(){ $('#cmdedit').hide();  })

Comment: I have tried this as well.<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function HideEdit() {
            alert($('#cmdedit'));
            var MyRoleList = "@me.rolelist@";
            if (MyRoleList.indexOf(",9875,") > -1) {
                $('#cmdedit').hide();
            }
        }
      
        setTimeout(HideEdit, 5000)
    });
</script>

Comment: Try $(window).on("load", function () {...}), it runs after everything (including images and iframes) are ready, and not just the DOM.

I'd also try the switchbut() function defined in the inline, system-generated script tag.

Other than that, I'd try to include your code in the system-generated script tags or the includes like  /js/ssfunctions.js.

The CSS approach might work with the important rule.

Also, validate MyRoleList.

Comment: I have tried $(window).on("load", function () {...}), it still doesn't work. I have tried putting my function in a separate js file and still no luck.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is a really bad problem statement. Maybe this "@me.rolelist@" thing isn't working. Are there any errors in the console? Also, you've got way too much code for hiding an element. See [mcve]. Note the word "Minimal"...

Comment: I am getting an alert. alert('aaa'); which means @me.rolelist@ is working. It doesn't work(I meant cmdedit is still visible. No errors in the console though.

Comment: I may not understand the question - but are you trying to modify content (hide a button) within an iFrame? If so, is the iFrame on the same domain as the page you're loading it on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to hide the element with id `cmdedit` from javascript code that is executing inside an `<iframe>`. But the element is not inside that `<iframe>` so jQuery cannot find it.

You need to tell jQuery where to look for the element. You can do it by passing a second parameter to jQuery selector. From jQuery Api [documentation page](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1):

> **[jQuery( selector [, context ] )](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1)**
>
> **selector**
>   Type: [Selector](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Selector)
>   *A string containing a selector expression*
>
> **context**
>   Type: [Element](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Element) or [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery)
>   *A DOM Element, Document, or jQuery to use as context*
>    -

So you just need to pass the **document object** of the **top window** to select the element to hide it.

```
    $(function(){
        $("#cmdedit", window.top.document).hide()
    });
```

> Or you can use the jQuery of the main window

```
window.top.$("#cmdedit").hide();
```

> Or you can use plain javascript

```
window.top.document.getElementById('cmdedit').style.display = 'none';
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('#cmdedit').css('display','none');
$('#cmdedit').css('height',0);
$('#cmdedit').css('width',0);
$('#cmdedit').css('visibility','hidden');
$('#cmdedit').css('position','fixed');
```

Position fixed must be combined with visibility hidden so it does not take space from document.

although is not the best practice, is a second way to get to the result.

Comment: Note that height, width, visibility, and position will be ignored because of `display: none`. Also, [`css()` can take an object](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties), so you don't need five lines of code...

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
<script>
        $(window).ready(function(){
            $('#cmdedit').hide();
        });
    </script>
```

Hope this help.